# Fuzzy name searching in MySQL, match against relevance

Tags: mysql, search

In my database, I have a company and a phone table. I have these entries:

> company name - phone number
>
> 'abramowitz pomerantz' - '555'
>
> 'a attorney at law' - '556'

I want to be able to search 'Abramowitz Pomerantz & Coffey' with phone number '555' and return a result.

However, when I search 'Aaba Attorney' with phone number '556', I do NOT want to return 'A Attorney at Law' even though they have the same phone number.

I can change the match against query so that it only returns results where "relevance" ("releveance" is defined here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html ) is greater than an arbitrary number.

The problem is that relevance changes based on other entries within the database.

So my question is if there is a method for returning relevance that ONLY looks at the row in question to return a number, so that, for example match (Aaba Attorney) against (Aaba Attorney) would return, 100%.

Comment: Yeah, this is what simple `=` does :)

Comment: Fulltext search is not suitable for fuzzy matching, it is designed to match words within longer texts. If you want to implement fuzzy matching, I suggest you use a proper programming language with a pre-designed fuzzy matching library instead of mysql.